# Else if condition its not working on scroll

Tags: jquery

The `else if` condition is not working. I want the condition to run but its not working, only the `if` condition is working

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function(e) {
  let scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (scroll > portfolio_button_container - 50) {
    $(".portfolio-button-container").addClass("fixed-portfolio");
  } else if (scroll <= 3691) {
    $(".portfolio-button-container").removeClass("fixed-portfolio");
    console.log("worked");
  }
});
```

Comment: This is due to short-circuit evaluation. If `scroll > portfolio_button_container - 50` is true, no other conditions will be evaluated. You need to restructure the logic to meet whatever the requirements are given this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

that's why because your if the condition will not true then it will check for the else if and otherwise it will not check for the else if condition